# Kivy RecycleView - elements appear from bottom

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have a problem with `RecycleView`. I guess I had to make trivial mistake because I haven't found with google someone with same problem.

The problem is, when I am adding new items to my `RecycleView` list, they appear from bottom, as is depicted on GIF below:

[image: GIF]

This is excerpt from my code:

```
class SelectableButton(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Button):
    index = None

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        """ Catch and handle the view changes """
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableButton, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)

    def on_press(self):
        self.parent.parent.parent.chose_device(self.device)
        print("Connecting to %d" % self.index)

class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior, RecycleBoxLayout):
    pass

class DeviceList(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DeviceList, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = []

class DiscoveryForm(BoxLayout):
(...)

    def new_device_discovered(self):
        self.disc_list_prop.data = []
        devices = self.discovery.get_discovered_devices()
        for i, device in enumerate(devices):
            self.disc_list_prop.data.append({'text': "Device " + device.mac, 'id': str(i), 'device': device})


    def chose_device(self, text):
        (...)
```

app.kv:

```
RootForm:
    Label:
        text: "Initialization"

<DiscoveryForm>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    platform_label_prop: platform_label
    disc_list_prop: disc_list
    Label:
        id: platform_label
        height: "40dp"
        size_hint_y: None
        text: "Discovery"
    Button:
        text: "Search for devices"
        height: "100dp"
        size_hint_y: None
        on_press: root.start_searching()
    DeviceList:
        id: disc_list
    Label:
        size_hint_y: 1
    Button:
        text: "Go to driver"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: "50dp"
        on_press: root.parent.show_driver_form()

<SelectableButton>:

<DeviceList>:
    viewclass: 'SelectableButton'
    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'   
        default_size_hint: 1, 1
```

I've tried to remove gap between first button and first discovered device button but there is no gap. I've also tried `vlayout` but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Replace `default_size_hint: 1, 1` with `default_size_hint: 1, None`
- Add `size_hint_y: None`
- Set minimum height, `height: self.minimum_height`

## Snippets

```
<DeviceList>:
    viewclass: 'SelectableButton'
    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'   
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
```